# How to move Unity Launcher to a different monitor?

Tags: unity, launcher

I have two monitors. The left monitor is set as primary, but the Unity Launcher appears on the right monitor.

[image: dual screen issue]

How can I move it to the other monitor?

Comment: Needed to solve that me too xD PS : Where did you found this wallpaper ?

Comment: The wallpaper was [default in Fedora 11](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Artwork/F11/RC).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In Ubuntu 20.04, it's under Settings > Appearance > Dock > Show on:

[image: Screenshot of Settings/Appearance window]

Answer (score 20):

This is a bug:

- [Launcher is shown on the wrong screen in some multi-monitor setups](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/742544)

*(taken from the bug report)*

Permanent workaround (requires logging back in again):

Edit `~/.config/monitors.xml`, find the monitor you want the launcher to display on and change:

```
<primary>no</primary>
```

to:

```
<primary>yes</primary>
```

Now log out and log in again.

Temporary workaround (no logout required):

Open a Terminal window and...

1. Run `xrandr` to find the NAME of the output you would like to make primary.
2. Run `xrandr --output NAME --primary && nohup unity --replace &`

Comment: The workaround listed there fixed this. Thanks!

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/844605/ that is my monitors.xml file.. I have also attempted to run the listed command `sudo xrandr --output DVI-I-2 --primary && nohup unity --replace &` and the launcher still remains on my left (smaller) non primary monitor.

Comment: nevermind.. Just read the top of the page that there is no workaround for 11.10 but there is a ppa... gonna try that now.

Answer (score 3):

**If you are using Ubuntu 13.10 and up**

On the same window where you set your screen orientation (System Settings>Displays:Launcher Placement) you can set the screen(s) on which the launcher show show up:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It isn't configurable in 11.04, but it is a known issue and I think I've read that it's fixed in 11.10. Not sure though.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to try. You can follow the instructions [here.](http://erikimh.com/unity-move-vertical-launcher-to-another-monitor/)

In summary, run `xrandr` to get a list of your monitors. The first one listed (e.g. `VGA1`) will be your primary monitor. Then run `sudo xrandr --output VGA2 --primary` to make your second monitor primary. Note that your monitors may not be called `VGA1` and `VGA2`. You'll need to look at the `xrandr` output to find the correct names.

Secondly, your monitors look like they might have the same connection type. If that's the case, you could try switching the cables they use to connect.

Lastly, if all else fails, you could just switch the physical location of the monitors. Maybe not the best solution, but also probably the simplest.

Comment: Thanks. I ran the following command and it worked like a charm in ubuntu 11.04! sudo xrandr --output VGA1 --primary # VGA1 was my samsung bigger monitor

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu 18.10

go to display and set the primary display to the screen which you want to have the launcher:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for 11.10 there is no *workaround*, but there is a [ppa on launchpad](https://launchpad.net/~vanvugt/+archive/unity) (unsupported) that fixes the issue.

To install:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:vanvugt/unity`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install unity`

You will need to relog for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed the "[Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/)" extension (and perhaps forgotten about it, as I did), changes made to the Launcher location in Settings > Appearance will be ignored. Instead:

1. Right click on the Launcher
2. Choose "Extensions"
3. Click on the 'gear' button for "Dash to Panel"
4. Modify which monitor the panel is displayed on at the top:
   [image: screenshot showing option for "Display the main panel on: Primary Monitor"]