# Multi Monitor Setup

Tags: launcher, multiple-monitors, flash, external-monitor

I'm having some problems with a multi monitor setup in Ubuntu:

1. The launcher will appear on the laptop monitor if the external monitor isn't plugged in on startup. If the external monitor is plugged in on startup it will appear on that monitor. Is there a way to make it consistently appear on one screen, or if possible duplicate the launcher on both monitors?
2. If a flash video is playing on the external monitor and I make it fullscreen, the video will appear fullscreen on the laptop monitor. Conversely once the video is made fullscreen on the laptop monitor - If you click on the external monitor it comes off fullscreen.

Does anyone have any solutions to these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the driver.  On my laptop, I can set any of the monitors internal or external to be the "primary" and watch full screen flash on a TV connected via HDMI for example.  On my desktop I can fullscreen flash video on any monitor with xinerama...but the unmaximizing thing happens.  You can "fake" full screen using the zoom feature in firefox(control+mousewheel) and probably other browsers.

1 was answered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57833/how-to-move-unity-launcher-to-a-different-monitor).