# Lubuntu: Trouble moving Launcher Bar to right monitor

Tags: lubuntu, multiple-monitors, display, launcher

I'm using Arandr with Lubuntu 18.04 to extend my display to a 1200p Dell monitor. In Arandr, the laptop display is both active and marked as primary. However, the launcher bar stays with the left monitor. My laptop is on the right and I want the launcher bar to stay with it (it makes unplugging the monitor nicer to work with).

Is there any way to move the launcher bar to the right monitor?

**Tried**

Checking the panel settings for the bar. I did not see any option to move monitors. Even switching the edge setting from bottom to right, moved the bar to the right of the left positioned monitor.

[How to move Unity Launcher to a different monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57833/how-to-move-unity-launcher-to-a-different-monitor)

> run xrandr to get a list of your monitors. The first one listed (e.g.
>   VGA1) will be your primary monitor. Then run sudo xrandr --output VGA2
>   --primary to make your second monitor primary.

LVDS-1 is already listed first and marked `primary` under `xrandr`. VGA-1 is my extended 1200p Dell screen. It is not marked primary either. It is listed 2nd. Despite this it has the launcher bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on panel, in the `Geometry` it has a "Monitor" selection drop-down which allows you to switch which monitor the panel appears on (along with other settings).

[image]